# Insert PHP script in OpenCart static page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am working on news system not integrated with opencart admin panel (I dont need this), but I want to display data on my custom opencart page, which is using template.

I made php script which display my news from other database, but I have not idea where to put this.

In few word - I want to execute my own script only on one opencart page (for example in custom page created in information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution at opencart forum :) - http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=136937